# fail to return sorted shell list

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I have constructed a shell sort algorithm from PseudoCode and C code in a Python Script..

(I am working through algorithms as an exercise)

I cannot seem to get the sorted list to return

when i print(inner) as part of the loop, it does indeed print them out in order 1 by 1 and ends..

2 
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

I have tried to return inner from the function

the response i getis [[9]]

which is the last iteration.. so i know it iterates, sorts correctly..

However I cannot get it to return the sorted list

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

```
unsort_list = [4, 6, 3, 2, 1, 9, 7, 8, 5]

def shell(a):
    """ 
    Step 1 − Initialize the value of h
    Step 2 − Divide the list into smaller sub-list of equal interval h
    Step 3 − Sort these sub-lists using insertion sort
    Step 3 − Repeat until complete list is sorted

    """

    interval_h = 1
    i = 0
    l = len(a)
    elements = a
    inner = []
    outer = []
    value_ins = []

    print(l)

    while interval_h <= l / 3:
        interval_h = interval_h * 3 + 1

    while interval_h > 0:
        outer = interval_h
        for i in elements:
            while outer < i:
                outer += 1
                value_ins = [outer]
                inner = outer

                while inner > interval_h - 1 and [inner - interval_h] >= value_ins:
                    inner = [inner - interval_h]
                    inner -= interval_h

            inner = value_ins

        interval_h = (interval_h - 1) 
        i += 1
    return inner

sorted_list = [shell(unsort_list)]
print(sorted_list)
```

Comment: What does the program **currently** return? Add this to your post.

Comment: On the line with `while outer > i` which `i` is it referring to: the `i` initialised right after `interval_h` or the `i` mentioned in `for i in elements`?

Comment: Shell sort could be done in-place without creating extra lists. Also note that you cant compare lists and integers (as in `outer < i`) and list assignment (like `inner = outer`) does not copy list but creates reference to that original list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much stripping and rebuilding after taking on board the above advice I have come to this solution using enumerate.

Thanks for the advice

```
def maf_shell(a):
    """ 
    Step 1 − Initialize the value of h
    Step 2 − Divide the list into smaller sub-list of equal interval (h)
    Step 3 − Sort these sub-lists using insertion sort
    Step 3 − Repeat until complete list is sorted

    """
    interval = len(a) // 2

    while interval:
        for i, j in enumerate(a):
            while i >= interval and a[i - interval] > j:
                a[i] = a[i - interval]
                i -= interval
            a[i] = j
        interval = 1 if interval == 2 else int(interval * 5.0 / 11)                



unsort_list = [4, 6, 3, 2, 1, 9, 7, 8, 5]  
maf_shell(unsort_list)

print(unsort_list)
```